# I need to solve EOM of lower limb with lagrange (Mathematica Code)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

The result eqs1........eqs6 didn't show. How can I fix this problem

````
g = 9.81;
x1 = -lH/2 sin[\[Theta]1[t]];
x1' = D[x1, t]
z1 = -lH/2*cos[\[Theta]1[t]];
z1' = D[z1 , t]
x2 = -lL/2*sin[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t]] - lHsin[\[Theta]1[t]];
x2' = D[x2 , t]
z2 = -lL/2*cos[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t]] - lHcos[\[Theta]1[t]];
z2' = D[z2, t]
x3 = -lF/2*sin[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t] + \[Theta]3[t]] - 
   lL*sin[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t]] - lH*sin[\[Theta]1[t]];
x3' = D[x3, t]
z3 = -lF/2*cos[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t] + \[Theta]3[t]] - 
   lL*cos[\[Theta]1[t] + \[Theta]2[t]] - lH*cos[\[Theta]1[t]];
z3' = D[z3, t]
x4 = -lH/2*sin[\[Theta]4[t]];
x4' = D[x4, t]
z4 = -lH/2*cos[\[Theta]4[t]];
z4' = D[z4 , t]
x5 = -lL/2*sin[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t]] - lHsin[\[Theta]4[t]];
x5' = D[x5, t]
z5 = -lL/2*cos[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t]] - lHcos[\[Theta]4[t]];
z5' = D[z5, t]
x6 = -lF/2*sin[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t] + \[Theta]6[t]] - 
   lL*sin[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t]] - lH*sin[\[Theta]4[t]];
x6' = D[x6, t]
z6 = -lF/2*cos[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t] + \[Theta]6[t]] - 
   lL*cos[\[Theta]4[t] + \[Theta]5[t]] - lH*cos[\[Theta]4[t]];
z6' = D[z6, t] 


T = m1/2*[x1' + z1']^2 + m2/2*[x2' + z2']^2 + m3/2*[x3' + z3']^2 + 
   m4/2*[x4' + z4']^2 + m5/2*[x5' + z5']^2 + m6/2*[x6' + z6']^2;
V = m1*g*z1 + m2*g*z2 + m3*g*z3 + m4*g*z4 + m5*g*z5 + m6*g*z6;
Lagrange = T - V

eqs1 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]1'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]1]
eqs2 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]2'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]2]
eqs3 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]3'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]3]
eqs4 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]4'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]4]
eqs5 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]5'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]5]
eqs6 = D[D[Lagrange, \[Theta]6'[t]], t] - D[Lagrange, \[Theta]6] ```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Moo : Yes. It's Mathematica code

Comment: @Moo : Thank you. Lagrange is a function that describes the state of a dynamic system in terms of position coordinates and their time derivatives and that is equal to the difference between the potential energy and kinetic energy compare hamiltonian.